# relation between eigenvalues matrix and eigenvalues of matrix projected on subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix and call $\mathcal{V}$ a subspace spanned by the columns of the orthonormal matrix $V$.
I was wondering if there exists theorems that gives me the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $V^T A V$ in function of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$.
I know already that the eigenvalues of $V^T A V$ are bounded by the eigenvalues by the eigenvalues of $A$ (Cauchy interlace theorem). Can someone help me with that?

many thanks

Comment: Apart from cauchy, I do not see anything else (even if you offer a  bounty worth +1000).

Answer (score 0):

$ V^T A V $ is known as a unitary similarity transformation of $ A $.

If $ A x = \lambda x $ then you can multiply both sides by $ V^T $ to get 
$ V^T A x = \lambda V^T x$.  Next, insert the identity  (since $V V^T = I $)
$ V^T A V V^T x = \lambda V^T x $.  Then place some parentheses strategically:
$ (V^T A V )(V^T x ) = \lambda ( V^T x ) $ and the answer stares you right in the face.

Notice that there is no requirement that  $ A $ be symmetric for this to work.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear, but $V$ is a subspace, so it is not necessarly of dimension equal to the dimension of $A$. This means that $V V^T$ is not equal to the identiy matrix and you need that in your proof.

Comment: This starts being incorrect from the first sentence.